# Django object has no attribute 'all'()

Tags: django, django-celery, django-users

Using Django, I am calling a webpush package to push notifications that includes the following function:

```
def send_notification_to_user(user, payload, ttl=0):
    from .models import PushInformation
    push_infos = user.webpush_info.select_related("subscription")
    for push_info in push_infos:
        _send_notification(push_info.subscription, payload, ttl)
```

This gives the error **"'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'select_related'"** referring to `push_infos`

Alternatively, I have changed `push_infos` to be:

```
push_infos = user.webpush_info.all()
```

This just returns that **"'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'"**

The only workaround I have figured out is:

```
push_infos = user.objects.get(username='user123').webpush_info.select_related("subscription")
```

This works well for the specific user I call on, but does not allow me to call this function for multiple users. Is there another way I can call all users through `push_infos`?

This is what the models.py looks like:

```
class PushInformation(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='webpush_info', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
subscription = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionInfo, related_name='webpush_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='webpush_info', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.user or self.group:
        super(PushInformation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise FieldError('At least user or group should be present')
```

This may be an amateur question but I haven't found the answer after reading through the Django docs for Users. For further context, this function works fine as part of the webpush package when I call the package through the shell. I am trying to automate notifications by using celery and that is where I am encountering this issue.

Comment: Can you share your model definitions? It would make easier to identify the problem

Comment: Thanks Joseba, I just edited my response to include the model definition